# Enderman Is troubling me

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

By mistake, I spawned an enderman in the creative mode. I even made a beautiful castle there. Will the enderman destroy it?

Comment: You should be able to do it in peaceful mode. Enemies cannot spawn or live in peaceful mode.

Comment: @TheIdiotGamer however Endermen are Neutral, if I am not mistaken, Neutral mobs can still spawn even on peaceful difficulty

Comment: They are neutral, but like spiders and zombie pigmen they're disabled by creative. Some neutral mobs can spawn in peaceful, others can't.

Answer (score 12):

The Enderman can take individual blocks from your world, but this is relatively rare so there's no chance of it completely destroying a building. (Also the blocks they can take a quite limited, so I doubt your castle is made of something an Enderman can pick up, [full list here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enderman) )

You could however set your game to peaceful mode which will instantly remove all hostile mobs and remove the chance of it taking any blocks at all.

Additionally (credit to AlfredPersonMc ), if you are on a PC version of Minecraft, the [command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands)

```
/gamerule mobGriefing false
```

Will stop any mobs from being able to damage the map, or pick up floating items without having to disable the mobs completely.

Comment: You could also run the command `/gamerule mobGriefing false` to disable endermen from removing blocks, creepers from making holes, and the enderdragon from deleting blocks (I think).